# T-sql subscript only numbers from string, cannot use create procedure, create table, etc

Tags: t-sql, ssms-2016

Similar questions have been posted in the past, but I work in a very limited environment.  The offered solutions involved using create procedure, create table, etc.  None of that is available here.  How can I subscript only digits (0-9) that are non-continuous from strings such as '09text10more text!@@#11' to return 091011?.  Is it possible with a combination of functions, something like SELECT Funtion1(Function2(StringField)) From Schema.Table?.  Data type is varchar(30).  Thank you.

---Update1---

I apologize, I am new to SQL and Stack Overflow and my question was not complete.  To answer some of your questions:

-RDBMS and version:
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      13.0.16106.4
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools    13.0.1700.441
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)     10.0.16299.15
Microsoft MSXML                 3.0 4.0 6.0

-Yes, I need to be able to execute this within the context of a single query.

I will try the separate suggested solutions and respond accordingly.

Thank you all.

---Update2---

Damien, SELECT @@version returns Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU1) (KB4135048) - 13.0.5149.0 (X64)   May 19 2018 09:41:57   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Thank you.

Comment: So, you need to be able to execute this within the context of a single query?

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Comment: You also need to recognise that the version information you're reporting is for the *client tools* you have installed. They tell us little about the version of the *server* you're connecting to, and most features depend on *that* detail rather than the client tools. Run `select @@VERSION` on the machine you're connecting to and add that information to your question (You can probably edit out the copyright notice if you're concerned about how long it is)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hack. :)

For my testing I used a variable but this will work with your field and a normal SELECT FROM query...

```
declare @textval nvarchar(max) = '09text10more text!@@#11'

SELECT 
    CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', SUBSTRING(@textval,1,1))=1 THEN SUBSTRING(@textval,1,1) ELSE '' END +
    CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', SUBSTRING(@textval,2,1))=1 THEN SUBSTRING(@textval,2,1) ELSE '' END +
    CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', SUBSTRING(@textval,3,1))=1 THEN SUBSTRING(@textval,3,1) ELSE '' END +
    CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', SUBSTRING(@textval,4,1))=1 THEN SUBSTRING(@textval,4,1) ELSE '' END +
    CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', SUBSTRING(@textval,5,1))=1 THEN SUBSTRING(@textval,5,1) ELSE '' END +
    CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', SUBSTRING(@textval,6,1))=1 THEN SUBSTRING(@textval,6,1) ELSE '' END +
... 
    CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', SUBSTRING(@textval,30,1))=1 THEN SUBSTRING(@textval,30,1) ELSE '' END
```

You basically need one case statement for every character in the field.

Answer (score 0):

You should always state RDBMS and version.

Valid TSQL for SQL Server 2017 and this requirement is below.

```
SELECT      yt.*,
            ca.extractedNumbers
FROM        dbo.YourTable yt
CROSS APPLY
            ( SELECT  STRING_AGG (d.character, '' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY d.Num )
                     FROM     ( SELECT character = SUBSTRING(StringField, Nums.Num, 1),
                                       Nums.Num
                                      FROM  (VALUES (01),(02),(03),(04),(05),
                                                    (06),(07),(08),(09),(10),
                                                    (11),(12),(13),(14),(15),
                                                    (16),(17),(18),(19),(20),
                                                    (21),(22),(23),(24),(25),
                                                    (26),(27),(28),(29),(30)
                                       ) Nums(Num)
                                      WHERE   Nums.Num <= LEN(yt.StringField) ) d
                     WHERE    d.character LIKE '[0-9]'
            ) ca(extractedNumbers)
```

For previous versions you can use

```
WITH Nums(Num) AS
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0))
FROM (VALUES (01),(02),(03),(04),(05),
             (06),(07),(08),(09),(10),
             (11),(12),(13),(14),(15),
             (16),(17),(18),(19),(20),
             (21),(22),(23),(24),(25),
             (26),(27),(28),(29),(30) )V(N)
)
SELECT yt.*,
       ca.extractedNumbers
FROM   dbo.YourTable yt
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT d.character AS [text()]
                    FROM   (SELECT character = SUBSTRING(StringField, Nums.Num, 1),
                                   Nums.Num
                            FROM   Nums
                            WHERE  Nums.Num <= LEN(yt.StringField)) d
                    WHERE  d.character LIKE '[0-9]'
                    ORDER  BY d.Num
                    FOR XML PATH('')) ca(extractedNumbers);
```

Comment: Martin, thank you.  I apologize I did not mention I use SSMS 2016, so STRING_AGG does not work.